# Description of Pfaffian System in Chern's Lectures on Differential Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

Here is a quotation from pg. 81, section 3-2 of Chern's *Lectures on Differential Geometry*:

> Suppose $L^r=\{X_1,\ldots,X_r\}$ is a smooth $r$-dimensional distribution on $M$. [$M$ is an $m$-dimensional manifold.] ... Locally, the distribution $L^r$ is therefore equivalent to the system of equations
>   $$
> \omega_s = 0, \ \ \ \ r+1\le s \le m,
> $$
>   often called a Pfaffian system of equations.

(The $\omega_s$ are differential $1$-forms such that $\langle X_i, \omega_s\rangle = 0$ for all $i,s$.)

This just seems very odd to me. The $\omega_s$ are *not* $0$, as far as I can tell. They are a bunch of differential $1$-forms that annihilate the members of $L^r$, but they are not actually $0$. More precisely, for any $X\in T^*(p)$, $X\in L^r(p)$ if and only if $\langle X,\omega_s \rangle =0$ for all $s$. Right? So in what sense is it true that $\omega_s=0$?

In most of these lectures, Chern is extremely clear and careful. Is there a particular reason he is not here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I write the equation $x=0$, I do not mean that $x$ is identically zero; I am referring to its solution set. Similarly, Chern is saying that the distribution is defined by the equations $\omega_r=0$. In particular, the subspace consisting of all tangent vectors $X$ at a point annihilated by all the $1$-forms is precisely the distribution at that point. Moreover, in the case that the distribution is integrable, the pullbacks of the $\omega_r$ to an integral submanifold (i.e., their restrictions) will be $0$ (and conversely).

Comment: OK. I think the key is in the last sentence: if the distribution is integrable, then the pullbacks are $0$, so in this sense, $\omega_r=0$.

Comment: No, only the restrictions are $0$. Take $\omega=dx$ in $\Bbb R^2$. Then $dx=0$ defines the distribution whose integral manifolds are vertical lines. But what about $\omega=dz-x\,dy$ in $\Bbb R^3$? $\omega=0$'defines a non-integrable 2-plane field.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the terminology here. (I'm following Chern's lectures and he doesn't use the term "pullback".) I thought what you meant is that if $M'$ is an integral submanifold and $f:M'\to M$ is an imbedding, then $f^*(\omega_s)=0$ where $f^*:A(M)\to A(M')$ is the mapping of exterior forms on $M$ to exterior forms on $M'$ induced by $f$. In this sense $\omega_s=0$. Is that what you mean? And if one wanted to "solve" for the integral submanifolds, one could write down $\omega_s=0$ and integrate.

Comment: Right. However, you can't always integrate. See the Frobenius Theorem (p. 35 and p. 82).